# How to calculate relaxation time to find the Stokes number?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

I would like to find the [Stokes number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_number) of aerosol particles in a flow to assess how closely they follow the streamlines. My flow is non-stokesian as it is turbulent.

Stokes number is defined as:

$\mathrm{Stk} = \frac{t_0 \,u_0}{l_0}$

where,

- $t_{0}$ is the relaxation time of the particle,
- $u_{0}$ is the fluid velocity of the flow well away from the
  obstacle,
- $l_0$ is the characteristic dimension of the obstacle.

I have a clear idea on what $u_{0}$ is, I know there diameter of the particles in my flow, which I can use as $l_0$.

But I am confused about how to obtain $t_{0}$. In Wikipedia, for Stokes flows, there is a formula: ${\displaystyle t_{0}={\frac {\rho _{p}d_{p}^{2}}{18\mu _{g}}}}$. However, as my flow is non-Stokesian, I am stuck.

The particles are DEHS, so I have an idea about their sizes and density, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: If you look further down in the Wiki article, they show an integral and then a graph which seems to be what you need